# Word (2010 to 365) Keyboard Shortcuts for Headings 4-9?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, troubleshooting

We recently upgraded from Office 2010 to MS Office Professional Plus. 
Most of the keyboard shortcuts in Word 2010 never worked as expected, and the same is true for 2019. I.e., by typing Ctrl + Alt + [1, 2, 3, ...,9]. (Pressing Alt + Ctrl + # has the same results at Ctrl + Alt + #).

First (based on posts in SE and elsewhere) we tried the following without success:

- Deleting normal.dotm to generate a new normal.dotm.
- Resetting the shortcuts in both a test docx file and the normal.dotm file (could not do this because "Reset" was not enabled in either file).
- Unchecking Add-Ins (there was nothing to uncheck; Adobe PDFmaker was the only add-in available and it was already disabled).

Next we did what we should have in the first place: We printed and compared the shortcuts from the ListCommands macro and from the [Office support site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2).

Both charts show that, indeed, MSoft code is the culprit for PCs and Macs, and going many years back and to the present. Here is what the charts show for each sequence:

- Ctrl + Alt + 1 = H1
- Ctrl + Alt + 2 = H2
- Ctrl + Alt + 3 = H3
- Ctrl + Alt + 4 = unassigned
- Ctrl + Alt + 5 = GoToObjectLayer
- Ctrl + Alt + 6 = unassigned
- Ctrl + Alt + 7 = unassigned
- Ctrl + Alt + 8 = unassigned
- Ctrl + Alt + 9 = unassigned

We tested the sequences directly (Customize Ribbon > Keyboard Shortcuts > Customize...) and yes, it's as noted above.

The next post in this thread states the solution that worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

Cycling through the keyboard customizations, we found that the Alt + # sequences had not been assigned. So we created shortcuts for all headings using Alt + #, and deleted the Alt + Ctrl + # sequences for H1-3.